# History of C Runtime library from Windows

Tags: c, dst, crt

Im curious - is there any known records of when specific parts of the c library where written for Windows?

Im especially interested in the _tzset, and the reasoning to only support american daylight saving when specifying a TZ variable. It would be interesting to know who was running the department that wrote this code and why they decided to do it completely different from how linux handles TZ.

Comment: Maybe https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanlon%27s_razor applies?

Comment: AIUI, Windows does support worldwide timezones reasonably well.  But it only attempts to handle (a) current zones and (b) current DST rules.  It does not attempt to know that location A moved from timezone B to timezone C in 1997.  It does not attempt to know that in 2005 timezone D changed its DST-start-date from the first Sunday in April to the last Sunday in March.

Comment: Now, of course, the tzdb project (used by most Unix, Linux, and Mac systems), *does* attempt to solve both of those problems.  But they're really hard problems, and the tzdb solution is pretty complicated.  I don't know for sure -- I'm totally speculating -- but I suspect Microsoft declined to adopt the tzdb project for some combination of its being (a) overkill and (b) not necessary for Microsoft's requirements and (c) Unix-based and (d) open source and (e) "Not Invented Here".  Microsoft has traditionally had a pretty strong affinity for stuff it invented, and an aversion to anything else.

Comment: As far as I have read and tested myself, _tzset dosent support DST outside of the US - if you supply a TZ variable. It does support other countries daylight saving if you have not set the TZ environment variable and it can instead default back to the OS settings instead.

Comment: It would be interesting to see what dates that Microsoft specific code was written. Since it is proprietary code, maybe it is impossible to get such information? But then again, it must have been introduced in some version of microsofts lib c and thus been mentioned in some kind of release note?